# Is it possible to observe Shapiro time delay if gravitational attraction is zero, but time dilation, as part of spacetime curvature is not zero?

Tags: spacetime, curvature, time-dilation

I understand it might not be very clear what I mean by the title so I will try describe it using simpler (but less accurate words). Unfortunately I cant use math to describe it. Sorry about that - I am not physicist, just an average dude trying to "relax" by letting his mind wonder after stressful business meeting. Thanks for understanding.

Scenario 1:

- Shapiro time delay - Laser beam would take little bit longer to reach
  its target, if on its way it goes close (5 meters close) to very massive object (lets call it object A) then if the object A was not there. (when
  observer from Earth)

Scenario 2:

- But what if we have two objects A (same A as in scenario 1) in small
  distance from each other. Lets say 10 meters away from each
  other(...lets assume they are not attracted to each other in this
  scenario...because of other forces not listed...)
- And than the laser beam goes directly between them, so 5 meters from each surface

Target of laser beam is same distance from observer/start in scenario 1 and 2

Question:
Will the laser beam reach its target in scenario 2 later than in scenario 1 ? 
And if so, will the "time delay" be the same as if it was going 5 meters close to object that is twice as massive as object A?

I am again sorry about the wording. I hope the point of my question is clear. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: It’s the same as in your previous question... the gravitational potential, not the gravitational force, is what matters for time stuff.

Comment: @safesphere Your answer seems fine to me. If you undelete, I’ll upvote it.

Comment: @safesphere When I went to upvote, it wouldn't let me. It turns out that I am the accidental downvoter! If you edit it, apparently I can correct my mistake. Sorry about that!

Comment: @safesphere Done!

Answer (score 3):

Your thinking is correct, the Shapiro delay would be longer in the second scenario. Two heavy objects would create a stronger spacetime curvature than just one of them. Time dilation is a part of spacetime curvature and will also be stronger causing a longer delay. The gravitational attraction of a test particle exactly between the objects is zero implying that the gradient of the time dilation there is zero, but the time dilation is larger, not smaller.

The delay would not be exactly twice longer, because the gravitational field is not linear. This means that the field of two objects is not a mere sum of the fields of each object, unlike in electromagnetism. It would be in the ballpark, but not exactly twice.

Comment: Thanks again for answering. I hope my followup idea/thought can be listed as comment, if not I will make a separate question...So when physics use "c" as a constant it applies only in this part of Milky Way...? Compared to observer on Earth - "c" in Andromeda can have little bit different value, or lets say "c" in the middle of the Boötes void will be "impacted" by different gravitational potential...when observed from Earth. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: $c$ is the same everywhere locally, but may be different remotely. It relates to the rate of time. Consider we both have wristwatches on both hands. I am in space, you are near a black hole where time is dilated. I measure the rate of my left watch by using my right watch as one second per second. You measure the rate of your left watch by using your right watch as one second per second. So my $c$ near me is the same as your $c$ near you, no matter where you are, but I see your $c$ being slower than mine while you see my $c$ being faster than yours.